# Trac wiki formatting traclink changeset

Tags: trac

For Trac wiki formatting, I want make the simplest trac link that points to a changeset in the repo browser. I'm able to get `changeset:<sha>/<repo>` to work as a traclink, for example `changeset:df12aa9/foo_repo`, however `[<sha>/<repo>]`, for example, `[df12aa9/foo_repo]` doesn't seem to resolve into a traclink. I expect the square bracketed format to work the same as the `changeset:` format. Am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to use 8 characters for the hash, at least until [#11992](https://trac.edgewall.org/ticket/11992) is resolved.

Comment: Ah, thanks for that. That didn't even pass my mind. `[git] shortrev_len = 8` in the trac.ini config should help out with things then